# Parsing unicode in tweets using python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I've tried all manner of approaches to reading in this (sample) of tweets from this file. The unicode character [Victory Hand](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/270c/index.htm) does not seem to want to parse. Here's the data sample.

```
399491624029274112,Kyle aka K-LO,I unlocked 2 Xbox Live achievements in WWE 2K14! http://t.co/wRIxZTjYWg,False,0,Raptr,,,,,2013,11,10,11,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
399491626584014848,Dots Group LLC,GeekWire Radio: Amazon vs. author  Xbox One first take  and favorite iPad apps - GeekWire http://t.co/jbbryoHpHe,False,0,IFTTT,,,,,2013,11,10,11,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2
399491630149169152,BETTINGGENIUS!,RT @xJohn69: Sergio Ramos giveaway!; XBOX + PS3; ; -RT; -Follow me and @NeillWagers; -S/Os appreciated; ; Goodluck http://t.co/D997faGSB5,False,0,Twitter for iPad,,,,,2013,11,10,11,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,2
399491635735953408,Princess of TV,Toy Story of Terror is amaze balls. Thanks Xbox for the free NowTV #disneyweekend,False,0,Twitter for iPhone,,,,,2013,11,10,11,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2
399491654136369152,Sam Hambre,'9 Things You Should Know Before Buying a PlayStation 4'  http://t.co/Q3Ma1R83cF,False,0,Buffer,,,,,2013,11,10,11,0,7,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0
399491655780167680,Rhi ✌,@Escape2theMoon that's done what? im not on rn obvs i dont even have access to an xbox :c ?,False,0,web,399490703761223680,Escape2theMoon,1404625770,,2013,11,10,11,0,7,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
```

You can see the victory hand in the second field of the last tweet.

What I want to do is build a long string from all of the tweets. Staring very simply, I cannot even process this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import codecs
import csv

current_file = codecs.open("C:/myfile.csv", encoding="utf-8")
data = csv.reader(current_file, delimiter=",")

tweets = ""

for record in data:
    tweets = tweets + " " + record[2].encode('utf-8', errors='replace')
```

I've tried many permutations of importing, encoding, concatenating, converting to unicode, etc... but I cannot get past the victory hand. The error I always receive is:

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-114-fd9b136abd74> in <module>()
----> 1 for record in data:
      2     tweets = tweets + ' ' + record[2].encode('utf-8', 'replace')

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u270c' in position 23: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I concatenate all of these tweets into a single string without unicode problems?

Comment: We don't know which line causes that exception.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Sorry -- I added more error text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with csv.reader which tries to convert unicode back to `ascii`. Note from the [csv docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv):

> This version of the `csv` module doesn’t support `Unicode` input. Also, there are currently some issues regarding `ASCII NUL` characters. Accordingly, all input should be `UTF-8` or printable `ASCII` to be safe; see the examples in section Examples.

As proposed, you can use this recipe [from the docs examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples):

```
def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    # csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
                            dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        yield line.encode('utf-8')
```

With `unicode_csv_reader` helper utility your code might be as follows (slightly modified to use a closure and a join istead of a loop):

```
from operator import itemgetter

tweets_fname = "C:/myfile.csv"

with codecs.open(tweets_fname , encoding="utf-8") as current_file:
    data = unicode_csv_reader(current_file, delimiter=",")
    tweets = u' '.join(map(itemgetter(2), data))
    encoded_tweets = tweets.encode('utf8', 'replace')
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll have to read more about operator and itemgetter. ✌